# How I change the max_input_vars in MAMP?

Tags: php, mamp-pro

When I send a form by POST, shows me this error:

"Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini."

I followed the instructions in this link:

http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/increase-php-memory-limit-with-mamp-pro.html

But did not work out.

I search the current php.ini in MAMP:

File > Edit Template > PHP > The PHP version you're running

But I did not find the max_input_vars in it, so I added this parameter in the php.ini and increase the limit to "3000".After that, I rebooted my MAMP server but the parameter did not change. Then I reviewed the phpinfo but still whit the same limit ( 1000), I mean, did not change...

Do you know how to fix it or where I can find the max_input _vars?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Wow, you must really hate your users (1,000 input on a form). Anyway, check that there isn't another php.ini somewhere in the file system that MAMP could be using.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to PHP under languages then click the arrow next to the PHP version number you will get the php.ini file for that version.

You should be able to find/add it there